# Now that ES2015 dynamic import() is widely supported, what are the advantages of ES2015 static import?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, import, es6-modules

I am using **ES2015 Modules** increasingly.

More often than not, I'm leaning towards loading modules via the dynamic `import()` syntax, using variations of the following pattern:

```
import(moduleURL.js).then(importedModule => myFunction(importedModule));
```

In early 2020, this seems to be an approach without pitfalls, given that `import()` now has near-universal browser support.

See: https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-module-dynamic-import

But does this also mean that static `import` statements like:

- `import * as myModule from 'moduleURL.js'`
- `import { myNamedExport } from 'moduleURL.js'`
- `import myDefaultExport from 'moduleURL.js'`

are now effectively (albeit not officially) deprecated?

If not - and my *guess* is that they are not effectively deprecated - what are the *concrete technical advantages* of static `import` statements over dynamic `import()`?

In what situations or contexts would I be well advised to use the former over the latter?

---

**Further Reading:**

- Static `import` statements:

  - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import
- Dynamic `import()`:

  - [Dynamically importing ES modules with import()](https://medium.com/@leonardobrunolima/javascript-tips-dynamically-importing-es-modules-with-import-f0093dbba8e1) by Leonardo Bruno Lima

---

**Why am I asking for the advantages of ES2015 static `import`?**

It's not just idle curiosity.

I'm looking to standardise certain processes in my workflow and I'm pretty happy with `import()`.

But before I adopt `import()` everywhere, I want to be sure that I'm not missing out on specific functionality or advantages offered by static `import` statements but absent from their younger, more dynamic counterpart.

Comment: Wow. I had no idea you could do `import(...)`. I would argue that the regular way of doing imports `import { something } from 'here';` is definitely not going anywhere. `import(...)` seems be more for only needing a specific `import` for a quick thing. Whereas `import { something } from 'here';` would imply you're going to use that import a couple of different times in your code. I personally don't think I'd ever use `import(...)` but it's cool to know it exists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to work with synchronous code than asynchronous code. While you *could* use dynamic import everywhere, that would require putting `.then`s (or top-level `await`s, once that's supported) everywhere. This alone would result in an annoying amount of syntax noise. It gets worse when you have to import multiple modules at the same time:

```
Promise.all([
  import('foo'),
  import('bar')
])
  .then(([foo, bar]) => {
    // do stuff with foo and bar
  });
```

compared to

```
import foo from 'foo';
import bar from 'bar';
```

Less syntax noise means less surface area for bugs.

Also note that while dynamic import is widely supported, it's not universally supported. A relatively small proportion of users are still on old Edge, or at FF 56 or below, or at Chrome 62 and below, or even on IE11. Some might think that it's better to provide scripts that will work for basically everyone, rather than just the vast majority. (This is one reason why Babel is still in such common usage today)

Comment: Thank you for that, @CertainPerformance. So in summary (and I'm not intending to be flippant here) the advantages of static `import` statements are 1) easier syntax and 2) slightly wider browser support.

Comment: Yes, that's it. Another thing is that being able to statically analyze everything that needs to be imported at once can make certain tooling easier - for example, if the modules are compiled together with Webpack or some build system, rather than native ES6 modules. I don't have much experience with that, but I know that dynamic import will make figuring out the proper configuration a bit more difficult.

Comment: I've been experimenting more and I'm definitely experiencing having to add asynchronous markers (`.then()`, `async`, `await` etc.) everywhere so I absolutely take your opening point.